# Is the cost function fixed or something to be estimated?

Tags: estimation, optimization, loss-functions

Is the cost function or loss function something you fixed before running the optimization algorithm or something you have to estimate such as in the case of regularized regression?

Comment: If you don't have a cost function, just what are you optimizing??

Comment: Great point, so in cross validation, you have to test all different variants of the cost function and compare cost functions? Is cross validation empirical comparison of cost functions?

Comment: In cross validation you run the algorithm across all different kinds of cost functions and find the one with least error metric?

Comment: In cross validation you run the algorithm across different *set of estimated parameter values*, assess how well it is doing by calculating the cost function, and find the one with the least error metric. The formula of cost function used is the same for all the folds of crossvalidation. The estimated model parameters differ because the training data differ.

Comment: Aren’t there infinite possible folds? Because all the combinations of training data grouped together.

Comment: Does Cross validation give us a solution that has average least test error or simply the minimum of the test error?

Comment: Technically there are *many, many* possible folds. But cross validation does not use *every possible configuration of training set*. It rather splits the dataset beforehand into (typically) 5 similar-sized chunks, and use 1 chunk to be its validation set, each for once.

Comment: Cross validation does not give solution. It gives you more honest estimate of the algorithm's performance.